# Laravel compact pass class variable

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to pass class variables using Laravel compact method?

Below, I have the `$fields` variable and it gets initialized via the constructor method.

```
class EventTypeController extends Controller
{
    protected $fields;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fields = Fields::all();
    }

    ...
```

Now is there a way to pass the above variable using compact method? I tried to directly type the variable name as normal, but it didn't work.

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $event_types = EventType::all(); 
    return view('event_types', compact('event_types', 'fields'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[compact](https://www.php.net/compact) (which isn't a Laravel specific function) only supports variables in the current scope and can't retrieve variables from object properties.

You'll have to specify the inclusion by providing it via an array instead of `compact`:

```php
return view('event_types', ['event_types' => $event_types, 'fields' => $this->fields]);
```

Answer (score 1):

compact actually return an array, you can return an explicit array:

```
return view('event_types', ['event_types' => $event_types, 'fields' => $this->fields]);
```

or you can use array_merge:

```
return view('event_types', array_merge(compact('event_types'), ['fields' => $this->fields]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assing variable to fields like below

```
$fields=$this->fields;
compact('event_types', 'fields'));
```

As per official php documentation

> compact() looks for a variable with that name in the current symbol
> table and adds it to the output array such that the variable name
> becomes the key and the contents of the variable become the value for
> that key. In short, it does the opposite of extract().

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 return view('event_types', compact('event_types'))
->with("fields",$this->fields);
```

Comment: It's viable. But I insist on using compact Milad.

Comment: i dont think its possible but you can set your class variable into another variable and then send that.
 
$variable2 = $this->fields;
....
compact('variable2')